# javascript slideshow malfunctioning after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote this simple code to make a basic slideshow for my website. This code works fine for a while but after that it starts malfunctioning, I mean the image don't load appropriately, the same image suddenly pops ups and fades and then slowly appears back again. 
I though something could be wrong withe the SetTimeOut timing, but I've played with it a alot and it didn't solve my problem:

```
    var x = 1;
    function F() {
        $('#Left').html("<img src='Images/" + x + ".jpg' />").fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
        if (x < 3) { x++;}
        else { x = 1; }
        setTimeout("F()", 7000);
    }
```

My question is what could be wrong with the simple code and how could I fix it or improve it.

Comment: Hmmm... dunno if this is the problem, but I'd suggest using `setTimeout(F, 7000)` instead of using the string `"F()"`.

Comment: Also you can just use `hide()` instead of `fadeOut(0)`

Comment: Thanks but the "F()" is not the problem, as I said the picture don't appear well after a while which has nothing to do with F or "F()", it is something related to the time interval in the loop, but I don't know how it should be solved.

Comment: @rossipedia: Your second comment solved the problem :) Thank you very much indeed roossipedia :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have a problem with the fade operations not taking exactly 7 seconds, but your timeout being scheduled for 7 seconds so over time, the two aren't lining up properly.  You can make them line up perfectly with no accumulating error by starting the next animation when the last fade is done with the completion function.

```
   var x = 1;
   function F() {
        $('#Left').html("<img src='Images/" + x + ".jpg' />")
            .fadeOut(0)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(1000, F);
        if (x < 3) { x++;}
        else { x = 1; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfect, I have another question, do you know how I can make the image fade into another one, I tried to use FadeTo but the slideshow stopped after the first images faded.

Comment: @FirstLast - If you want one image to fadeout while the other is fading in, then the usual way to do that is to have two images on top of one another and you fade one out and fade one in.